# Как преобразовать буквы в двоичную систему в С#?

Tags: c#

Нужно буквы преобразовать в двоичную систему счисления. Пользователь вводит слово и после нажатия на кнопку получает результат в виде двоичной системы.

Comment: Помогите, пожалуйста. Нужно было слово (символьное значение) перевести в двоичную систему С#. Сделала следующее: задала символы с переводом на десятеричную систему, а затем в двоичную. Столкнулась с такой проблемой. Считает один только символ ввода. Как сделать, чтоб при вводе нескольких символов выдавало счет всех, а не одного. Пример: рак=240.224.234=11110000.11100000.11101010 (должно быть так).

Answer (score 2):

[[@Spectre](/users/3159/spectre)](/users/3159/spectre) использовал язык linq запросов. Но вы с этим ещё незнакомы, поэтому в более простой форме это будет:

```
var t = "sdfsdgdsg";
for (int i = 0; i < t.Length; i++)
    Console.Write(Convert.ToString(t[i], 2));
```

статический класс Convert содержит методы для преобразования одних типов данных в другие. В частности ToString преобразует (iтый символ строки неявно преобразованный в byte) к двоичной строке (основание 2)

Comment: не подскажешь как заменить  t="fghjkl" на t=  вводимый пользователем символ или букву. заранее спасибо.

Comment: ``var t = Console.ReadLine();``

Comment: Если один символ то var t = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar

Answer (score 1):

я бы сделал так:

```
 result = text.Aggregate(string.Empty, (acc, ch)=>acc+ConvertCharToBin(ch));
```

метод `ConvertCharToBin` принимает букву(char) возвращает её довичный код(string)

Comment: К сожалению, в вашем методе я не разобралась, у меня больше вопросов возникло, нежели решила проблему. Я написала в Visual Studio С# 2010 в режиме ConsoleApplication.